# CKEditor 3.6.1: Load editor on event

Tags: ckeditor

I create a page with multiple tabs. 
On one of my tabs I want to use CKeditor on a textarea, so when I display my table I call:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('MyTextArea', MyOptions );
```

I have the UI of the editor but when I click on the text area nothing append, I can't edit it. The solution for access to the text area is to use "tab" for accessing this field. 
I try to put a default value and I can edit if I click on the text but if I click elsewhere in the area I cannot edit.

I have this problem for IE10 and I need it works on it. It's working on Chrome and Firefox. I use CKEditor 3.6.1 and I cannot upgrade it.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problems do you have on IE10 and you didn't make it possible for us to quickly see them. Also, it's a very short-term solution to not upgrade CKEditor, because so old version will not work with either IE11 or Edge.

Comment: I have no error with IE10, my problem is when I click on the text area of the CKEditor, the cursor doesn't display and I can't write text in the text area. I can't upgrade beacause of the licence. The 3.6.1 is compatible with IE8 so it's too with IE10 normally

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the z-index of the container of my textarea, I change it and it works.